# Prevent multiple add_to_head() calls

Tags: add-on-development, custom-fields, fieldtype

In `function display_field()`, if a fieldtype needs to use `ee()->cp->add_to_head('/path/to/foo.css')` and `ee()->cp->add_to_foot('/path/to/bar.js')`, how can I get it to do so only once, even when the Publish page may have multiple instances of that field?

Comment: Was my answer below helpful?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the session cache:

```
if (ee()->session->cache(__CLASS__, __FUNCTION__) === FALSE)
{
  ee()->cp->add_to_head('/path/to/foo.css');

  ee()->session->set_cache(__CLASS__, __FUNCTION__, TRUE);
}
```

Your code will only run once per page load.